# How to delete a debian luks swap partition properly?

Tags: swap, luks

There is the post [Removing the swap partition from a LUKS encrypted SSDD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403826/removing-the-swap-partition-from-a-luks-encrypted-ssdd) but it's tagged as linux mint.

Because of the fact that update-initramfs (a debian tool) reports an error my problem is related to debian.

I removed the entry from /etc/fstab and deleted the swap partition using gparted.

The problem is when I login it loads very long and when I run "apt upgrade" I got an error when it tried to update the initramfs. I cannot show you the error message because i reinstalled debian now. But this shouldn't be necessary because it's clear what the problem is.

When I boot there is a mapper device created under /dev/mapper/luks-... and then this device is mounted as a swap device. By removing the line from /etc/fstab the mount is no longer done. But it still tries to create the mapper file. And that fails if I delete the partition. So I have to stop debian from trying to create the mapper file.

The problem is that the swap partition is still referenced in these files:

```
/etc/crypttab
/etc/default/grub.ucf-dist
/etc/default/grub
```

I think removing the partition from crypttab is not a problem.

But the other files? Should I edit them or is there a command line tool? I don't know.

Comment: I guess `grub.ucf-dist` might be irrelevant given that `/etc/default/grub` exists:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/cwoer2/comment/eyid29y/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Then you probably want to show us these lines from the last mentioned file.

Comment: @saulius2 I installed debian bullseye (from scratch) and removed the swap partition from all 3 files. The swap partition is referenced by grub as "resume=/dev/...". I also had to run "update-initramfs -u" but now I got rid of the swap partition. The problem is it was not possible (to me) to install encrypted debian without swap partition. But now everything is fine.